Can anyone improve my batch rename script to make it recursive?
I have a Synology NAS that went nuts and it's full of .tmp files that used to be Excel, PDF, Word, etc.,...
I have this script that works fine inside a folder.
I've searched for days before asking here.
How can I make it recursive to all subfolders?
for f in *.tmp; do
    ext=''
    case $(file -b "$f") in
        *Excel*) ext='.xlsx' ;;
        *Word*)  ext='.docx' ;;
        *PowerPoint*)  ext='.pptx' ;;
        *PDF*)   ext='.pdf' ;;
        # etc...
        *) continue ;;
    esac
    mv "${f}" "${f}${ext}"
done


Assuming you want to apply the replacements to every subdirectory
find . -type f -name '*.tmp' -exec sh -c '
    f=$1
    case $(file -b "$f") in
        *Excel*) ext=.xlsx ;;
        *Word*)  ext=.docx ;;
        *PowerPoint*)  ext=.pptx ;;
        *PDF*)   ext=.pdf ;;
        # etc...
        *) continue ;;
    esac
    echo mv "${f}" "${f}${ext}"' _ {} \;


Remove the echo once you have verified the output makes sense.

One more thing , could you add a line to delete zero bytes files please?

@manuchap find . -type f -name '*.tmp' -size 0 -delete, no need to clutter the rename script with this.

Use zsh for any file manipulation that doesn't need to be portable. It's just simpler (even if the benefits are relatively limited in your case compared to typical file renaming questions).
To traverse subdirectories recursively, use **/.
for f in **/.tmp; do
  …

For batch renaming, use the zmv function. It takes care of a lot of things, including checking for existing targets, checking for duplicates (two files getting renamed to the same name), correctly handling all file names (your script breaks if a file name starts with a -), etc. It skips files if their new name is identical to their old name.
If you're unsure, run zmv -n … first to see a printout of what it would do. If you're happy, run the command again without the -n option.
Here's a zmv version of your task.
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
autoload zmv
function guess_extension {
  local ext=
  case $(file -b -- $1) in
    *Excel*) ext=.xlsx;;
    …
  esac
  print -r $1$ext
}
zmv '**/*.tmp' '$(guess_extension $f)'

Here's a modified version that removes the .tmp part.
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
autoload zmv
function guess_extension {
  local ext=
  case $(file -b -- $1) in
    *Excel*) ext=.xlsx;;
    …
  esac
  if [[ -n $ext ]]; then print -r ${1%.tmp}$ext; else print -r $1; fi
}
zmv '**/*.tmp' '$(guess_extension $f)'

I recommend using file -I or file --mime-type for more robustness. For example, case $(file -b <$1) in *Excel*) … catches Excel templates which should have the extension .xltx. You can make that matching more precise with case $(file --mime-type -b -- $1) in application/vnd.ms-excel) ….

Should it be for f in ***/.tmp; do or for f in **/.tmp; do?  (i.e. two or three *?)

@Greenonline Should be **. *** was a typo. (*** would kind of work: it's the same as **, but also follows symbolic links, which is almost never the right thing.)

I thought it might be a typo. Hmm, interesting, I didn't know about the sym-link following. Thanks.

I don't think you mean recursive, as that would involve the script calling itself. You probably mean iteratively search sub-directories.
Simple fixes to your original script
Try adding */ to the *.tmp, like so:
for f in */*.tmp; do
    ext=''
    case $(file -b "$f") in
        *Excel*) ext='.xlsx' ;;
        *Word*)  ext='.docx' ;;
        *PowerPoint*)  ext='.pptx' ;;
        *PDF*)   ext='.pdf' ;;
        # etc...
        *) continue ;;
    esac
    mv "${f}" "${f}${ext}"
done

The above will work for just one level of sub-directories (you do not state in your answer how deep your sub-directories go).
If you have multiple levels of sub-directories, then you should use the following script, instead (which uses **/*.tmp instead of */*.tmp):
for f in **/*.tmp; do
    ext=''
    case $(file -b "$f") in
        *Excel*) ext='.xlsx' ;;
        *Word*)  ext='.docx' ;;
        *PowerPoint*)  ext='.pptx' ;;
        *PDF*)   ext='.pdf' ;;
        # etc...
        *) continue ;;
    esac
    mv "${f}" "${f}${ext}"
done

This will work fine in ksh.
However, if you are using bash (vesion 4 and above), then you will need to prefix the script with shopt -s globstar, like so:
shopt -s globstar

for f in **/*.tmp; do
    ext=''
    case $(file -b "$f") in
        *Excel*) ext='.xlsx' ;;
        *Word*)  ext='.docx' ;;
        *PowerPoint*)  ext='.pptx' ;;
        *PDF*)   ext='.pdf' ;;
        # etc...
        *) continue ;;
    esac
    mv "${f}" "${f}${ext}"
done

See this answer to Recursive glob? for the various caveats of using globs in bash.

Actual recursion
If you really do want a recursive way of doing things, you could use the following script.
it runs through the contents of the directory, as before (in your original version), but if it finds a sub-directory, it calls itself  (i.e. recursion) and starts a new script (sort of - see last line), and so on. Once the sub-directory (or sub-directories) have been exhausted, the recursively called script ends and the calling script continues on its merry way - and so on and so forth.
It takes one parameter, the path to your directory that you want to search, so you now don't have to run the script whilst in the directory to search (you can run it from anywhere):
#!/bin/bash

search_dirs () {
    shopt -s nullglob dotglob

    for the_path in "$1"/*; do
        if [ -d "$the_path" ]; then
            search_dirs "$the_path"
        else # Your original script
            ext=''
            case $(file -b "$the_path") in
                *Excel*) ext='.xlsx' ;;
                *Word*)  ext='.docx' ;;
                *PowerPoint*)  ext='.pptx' ;;
                *PDF*)   ext='.pdf' ;;
                # etc...
                *) continue ;;
            esac
            mv "${the_path}" "${the_path}${ext}"
            printf '%s renamed %s.\n' "${the_path}" "${the_path}${ext}"
        fi
    done
}

To be more accurate, it isn't the script that is recursive, it is the function, search_dirs(), that is recursive.
Reference:

Recursive shell script to list files

Using find ... -exec
nohillside beat me to it with a superior version, but here are a couple of (messy) one liners.
Alternatively you could use find -exec, which is a bit more exhaustive when going through sub-directories. So, something like:
find . -type f -exec bash -c '[[ $(file -b "'{}'") == *"PDF"* ]] ' \; -exec sh -c '
for src; do
  mv "$src" "${src}.pdf"
done' sh {} +

for each of the brief file (file -b) descriptions, i.e. Excel, Word, PowerPoint, PDF, and so on.
Or (essentially the same thing):
find . -type f -exec bash -c '[[ $(file -b "'{}'") == *"PDF"* ]] ' \; -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0.pdf}' "{}" \;

References:

This answer to Search for executable files using find command
Rename files using the -exec action of find
find -exec with multiple commands

